# How to Think About a Relational Database on the Web

Tags: language-agnostic, relational-database

I've been doing some simple web programming using python, and I have a basic understanding of most of the parts involved in generating and serving web pages. However, I have only a tenuous grasp on the use of Relational Databases as a way to store and retrieve data. I do understand the basics of SQL queries and database design, but am having trouble understanding what I should be doing to allow for concurrent access (among other things).

With that in mind I have a couple fairly specific questions. However, for each question, I'm only partially interested in the answer to the question itself. I'm mostly interested in whether or not I'm asking these questions in the right way. So here it goes:

- When using a relational database, how do you insure that multiple threads don't interfere with each other while writing to the database?
- Could having multiple threads accessing a database create a situation in which the data they are reading are out of sync?
- How should I manage permissions to read/write from a database?
- Are there things that don't belong in a database (images, large chunks of text)?

I'd love any commentary on these specific questions, or a pointer to any resource that describes the correct way of thinking about using a relational database on the web.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a lot of your concerns are abstracted away by a DBMS.  You don't generally need to stress the thread/concurrency related stuff.  What you can do is group inserts/updates/queries into transactions to make them more atomic and ensure that all or nothing happens.  such transactions can be rolled back if, for example, they are interfered with part way thru.

You don't mention what DB you use, but here is a small DB-agnostic intro to transaction.  Of course you should also check out official documentation for your database.

http://www.sqlteam.com/article/introduction-to-transactions

As far as 'what things don't belong in a database', images and large chunks of text are fine.  You can store binary blobs, you can store code if it makes sense for what you're doing.  One thing i'd suggest is that you consider whether it is in your interest to directly store images in the DB or to store paths/filenames for files sitting on your server instead.

Answer (score 1):

> what I should be doing to allow for concurrent access

You let the database handle that, it's what it is designed for.

---

> - When using a relational database, how do you insure that multiple threads don't interfere with each other while writing to the database?

The database will handle this. Sometimes this will mean that one of the queries will abort in order to avoid a deadlock. You need to detect this in your code.

> - Could having multiple threads accessing a database create a situation in which the data they are reading are out of sync?

Yes, this is possible. Not much you can do about it - it is a consequence of multiple threads reading/writing the same data. There are synchronization commands that you can use, but these can have an effect on performance.

> - How should I manage permissions to read/write from a database?

Through the database security mechanism, whatever they are.

> - Are there things that don't belong in a database (images, large chunks of text)?

Large files, though even that depends on the application. Store application data in your database.

Answer (score 0):

I would not expose a database directly to the web; I'd have a middle tier between clients and database to handle things like authentication and authorization, validation and binding, synchronization and isolation for database access, etc.

This would have the added benefit of letting me scale by adding more middle tier hardware.